# How to prevent image in Crystal Reports 10 from being cut off to the second page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm making a Crystal Reports template. The template has some text in the header and then it has an image. If the text has a few lines, the image is normal and allowed in the first page, but if the text has many lines the image will be cut off in the first page and second page. Could it have ways to prevent the image from being cut off to the second page, such as auto-rescaling the image size?

I tried can grow and other settings in Crystal Reports 10, but it didn't work.

[Report Design Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frccm.png)

Comment: can you post the image of design?

Comment: HI, I add report design. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Keep Object Together` in the properties of the image is checked. This will prevent CR to split your image across pages.

Comment: To help you further more details are required. How is your report designed, which sections do you have exactly, what properties are set for them, show an example of the wrong output and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Best option in this case would be Create another section and place the image in that section instead of text and image in same section, This will force the image to go to another page if it doens't fit in first page.

For E.g, if data in report header, create one more section Report Header a and place text in that section and Report Header b and place image in this section

Comment: now, my report template is page header to store content. and detail to store image. but is is not work.